# Mysql running total/cumulative sum with reset at each vendor

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

I have a table of data that I need to show the detail rows along with a running total that resets each time the vendor field value changes.

The source table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Vendor(
InvYear INT not null, 
InvQuarter INT not null, 
InvDesc1 INT not null, 
InvDesc2 INT not null, 
Vendor varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
Paid INT not null, 
Billed INT not null);
```

And the values in the table appear as:

```
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','1','5','Vendor001','0','4498');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','1','5','Vendor001','0','4700');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','1','5','Vendor001','0','11500');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','2','5','Vendor001','5698','16801');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','3','5','Vendor001','0','-1245');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','4','5','Vendor001','0','1000');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','5','5','Vendor001','0','0');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','5','5','Vendor001','37255','-37255');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','1','5','Vendor002','0','1200');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','1','5','Vendor002','2819','-1200');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','1','5','Vendor003','0','4700');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','2','5','Vendor003','0','4000');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','3','5','Vendor003','0','0');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','4','5','Vendor003','0','0');
INSERT INTO Vendor(InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed) VALUES('2020','3','5','5','Vendor003','0','0');
```

I am running code that looks like this:

```
SET @cum:=0;
SELECT InvYear,InvQuarter,InvDesc1,InvDesc2,Vendor,Paid,Billed,
(@cum:= @cum + Paid) as`Paid_cum`
FROM  Vendor
```

And the results I get look like this:

| InvYear | InvQuarter | InvDesc1 | InvDesc2 | Vendor | Paid | Billed | Paid_cum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 4498 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 4700 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 11500 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2 | 5 | Vendor001 | 5698 | 16801 | 5698 |
| 2020 | 3 | 3 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | -1245 | 5698 |
| 2020 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 1000 | 5698 |
| 2020 | 3 | 5 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 0 | 5698 |
| 2020 | 3 | 5 | 5 | Vendor001 | 37255 | -37255 | 42953 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor002 | 0 | 1200 | 42953 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor002 | 2819 | -1200 | 45772 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 4700 | 45772 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 4000 | 45772 |
| 2020 | 3 | 3 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 0 | 45772 |
| 2020 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 0 | 45772 |
| 2020 | 3 | 5 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 0 | 45772 |

but I need the results to look like this:

| InvYear | InvQuarter | InvDesc1 | InvDesc2 | Vendor | Paid | Billed | Paid_cum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 4498 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 4700 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 11500 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2 | 5 | Vendor001 | 5698 | 16801 | 5698 |
| 2020 | 3 | 3 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | -1245 | 5698 |
| 2020 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 1000 | 5698 |
| 2020 | 3 | 5 | 5 | Vendor001 | 0 | 0 | 5698 |
| 2020 | 3 | 5 | 5 | Vendor001 | 37255 | -37255 | 42953 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor002 | 0 | 1200 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor002 | 2819 | -1200 | 2819 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 4700 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 2 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 4000 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 3 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | 5 | 5 | Vendor003 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are using the now considered "old" version of MySQL 5.x. Is it so? Answers vary wildly between MySQL 5.x and 8.x.

Comment: You need to set `@cum` back to `0` whenever the vendor ID changes.

Comment: we are using mariadb 10.1